# SQL to install a database program

Tags: sql, database, installation

Is it possible to use [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) to install a database program?

If so, even in theory, how?

The question refers to the following comment:

> 7.They used SQL to install a database program.

From the following document:

http://mirror.wikileaks.info/leak/us-intel-wikileaks.pdf

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of "program"?  Which database?  Not sure your question even makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean a stored procedure? If so, yes, those are managed by SQL.

Comment: Do you mean "Can I run a SQL script that installs a database?" Please help us by clarifying your question.

Comment: @DaveJarvis - you've been an active participant in SO for long enough to understand that this is a poorly phrased question.  Please give us some more details.

Comment: Considering its from a wikileaks document, it probably meant they used SQL injection to install some kind of spyware. While I agree the question is malformed from a technical point of view, the OP did give reference to the context.

Comment: @JP19: That is not a correct interpretation of the context. The heading for the section reads: "Appendix B: Methodology Used by Authors for Analysis of Leaked Tables of Equipment..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey if you read the PDF doc, it all becomes clear.

This is a(n alleged) US intelligence analysis of wikileaks' capabilities and means. The report is meant to be read by non technical people really, so my guess is that someone took a bit of a short-cut to explain the basics. This is not, as far as I can read in 2 minutes, a technical report, though it uses a lot of technical terms. To me it seems more like a legal/information report.

So the meaning of the sentence in question is lost. Clearly SQL scripts can be used to populate a database with entries (amongst many other qualities, such as triggers or other intelligent code that works in the database), but it cannot in its normal function be used to actually install any database software of any kind. Unless maybe there is a vulnerability exploit that allows one to launch arbitrary code from an SQL query. But that'd be a whole other game and I could see no mention of that in the report.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a database program as in "create a database", then sure, that's the DDL (data definition language) arm of SQL. `CREATE TABLE etc...`.

If you mean actually install a database, such as MySQL, Oracle, DB2, etc.., then no... THat'd be like saying "can I use a car to build a car?"